# How can I render an animation without any texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

A long time ago I remember doing a blocking animation in cycles that didnt had any textures when I toggled on metadata (thats as far as I remember from a tutorial), I've been trying to achieve the same thing in 2.79 but it seems its not working or I'm doing something wrong.

I mainly want to render without textures to save time and see if my animation is looks okay.

Comment: on the bottom of your 3d view, on the right of the horizontal menu bar, there's a button called OpenGL Render Active Viewport, if you click on it you have a quick render without any texture, is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Can't believe I forgot about that button. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In 2.79 and previous versions: On the bottom of your 3d view, on the right of the horizontal menu bar, there's a button called **OpenGL Render Active Viewport**, if you click on it you have a quick render without any texture. The file will end in the folder you choose in the *Properties* > *Render* > *Output* panel.

[image]

Since 2.8: In the 3D view header menu > *View > Viewport Render Animation*:

[image]